# Entire SharedPreference not getting cleared

Tags: java, android, session, sharedpreferences

I am creating two SharedPreferences file to maintain my sessions in my app.

While I create a Logout functionality in the app, the SharedPreferences do not get cleared and when the next user tries to login, he still sees the previous user details or no detials at all.

Here are my two files for the SharedPreferences:-

StorageHelper.java

```
public class StorageHelper 
{
    private static Context myContext = Login.getMyContext();
     public static Login myLogin = new Login();
     public String deviceId;
     public static String UserDataFile = "UserData";
     SharedPreferences localSettings;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public StorageHelper(String deviceID) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        deviceId = deviceID;
    }


    public StorageHelper() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public  void SetDeviceId(String deviceId)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          localSettings = myContext.getSharedPreferences(UserDataFile,0);
         editor = localSettings.edit();
        editor.putString("DeviceId",  deviceId);
        editor.commit();

    }
       public  String GetDeviceId()
      {
          String deviceId = "";
          localSettings = myContext.getSharedPreferences(UserDataFile,0);
          if (localSettings.contains("DeviceId"))
          {
              deviceId = localSettings.getString("DeviceId", "Nothing found");
          }
          return deviceId;
      }

    public static Boolean GetRegistrationInformation() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public  void SetRegistrationInformation(Boolean value) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         localSettings = myContext.getSharedPreferences(UserDataFile,0);
         editor = localSettings.edit();
       editor.putBoolean("Registration", value);
       editor.commit();


    }

    public void ClearData() 
    {
         localSettings = myContext.getSharedPreferences(UserDataFile,0);
         editor = localSettings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

SessionManagement.java

```
 SharedPreferences pref;

        // Editor for Shared preferences
        Editor editor;

        // Context
        Context _context;

        // Shared pref mode
        int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

        // Sharedpref file name
        private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserDetails";

        // All Shared Preferences Keys
        private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

        // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
        public static final String KEY_EMAILID = "email";

        // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)

        public static final String KEY_DEVICENAME = "devicename";
        public static final String KEY_USERSNAME = "usersname";


        public static final String  KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED = "deviceregistered";
        // Constructor
        public SessionManagement(Context context)
        {
            this._context = context;
            pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor = pref.edit();
        }

        public void createLoginSession(String emailId, String deviceauthurl, String deviceid, String endpointhost, String devicename, String usersname, String encodedaccountname, String hosturl)
        {
            // Storing login value as TRUE
            editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
                        editor.putString(KEY_DEVICENAME,devicename);
            editor.putString(KEY_USERSNAME, usersname);


            // commit changes
            editor.commit();
        }

        /**
         * Get stored session data
         * */
        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails()
        {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

            user.put(KEY_DEVICENAME, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICENAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_USERSNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERSNAME, null));


            // return user
            return user;
        }
        /**
         * Check login method wil check user login status
         * If false it will redirect user to login page
         * Else won't do anything
         * */
        public void checkLogin()
        {
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isLoggedIn())
            {
                // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                  _context.startActivity(i);
            }

        }

       // This function clears all session data and redirect the user to LoginActivity
        /**
             * Clear session details
             * */
            public void logoutUser()
            {
                // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
                //editor.clear();

                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICENAME);

                editor.remove(KEY_USERSNAME);
                e
                editor.remove(PREF_NAME);
                editor.commit();

                // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                _context.startActivity(i);
            }

            public boolean isLoggedIn()
            {
                return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
            }
```

I cleared data like:-

```
  case R.id.action_settings:

        StorageHelper helper  = new StorageHelper();
        helper.ClearData();

        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());
        session.logoutUser();

        finish();

        return true;
```

Comment: "he still sees the previous user details or no detials at all".?? so its random??

Comment: Only 1 sharedPreferences should be enough here, have you considered merging the 2?

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 I haven't can you show me how

Comment: @Rod the user doesnt see his details

Answer (score 0):

From the *[docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)*:

> "Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately "

Also from the *[docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)*:

> "For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of
>   this class (SharedPreferences) that all clients share"

This means that you are trying to modify the same (and only) copy of `SharedPreferences` from two different locations and since `commit()` writes to disk (which is expensive) there is inconsistency (last commit take precedence).

First step to solve the issue is to realize that you have only one instance of `SharedPreferences` and that you're accessing the same instance from different places - which might create a race-condition. Considering that, the right thing to do is re-design your software to consider it!

You can try and use `apply()` before you use commit which supposed to be safer (since it changes the "in-memory" object which is much faster than write-to-disk), or even add synchronization mechanism - but that would be incorrect use of `SharedPreferences`, even if it patches the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use this way to clear your data

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref",0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.clear();      //its clear all data.
 editor.commit();  //Don't forgot to commit  SharedPreferences
```

Comment: chk whether your data is saved in db